# Highlight elements on cross origin page

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, cross-domain, developer-tools

I need to accomplish something very similar to the "inspect element" functionality with Chrome developer tools (see attached screenshot). [image]

The main thing I'm looking for is the ability to recognize and highlight an element on the given page. I can display an overlay, add a class to the element, etc. I know that using an iFrame and trying to access and manipulate the DOM w/in the iFrame won't work directly because its cross-domain. I also know about post messages if you have control over the site, but I may not have that all the time. The main issue I have is that I am only trying to temporarily highlight elements on a page as if I had clicked "inspect element" and displaying that. It doesn't need to persist or anything, just to highlight specific elements (h1 tags for example), when the user loads a website within my app. Even the ability to use the chrome developer tools where it lets you "edit as HTML" would work if there were a way to do so.

Is there any way, using an iFrame, a new tab, or any other means that I can use to highlight elements on a given website who's URL is provided? I've attached another image of the "goal".
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have three options to highlight the elements.

**1. Browser Extension**

**2. Send events through postMessage to direct the iframe site to manipulate its DOM**

**3. Send events through postMessage to receive information about the positioning of the DOM and overlay elements on top of the iframe.**

#1 seems to be a longer overhaul to do. #2 and 3 is only possible if you will always have access to the website in the iframe.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

> The window.postMessage() method safely enables cross-origin communication between Window objects; e.g., between a page and a pop-up that it spawned, or between a page and an iframe embedded within it.